# Вертикальное меню на уровне с header

Tags: html, css

Уже долго ломаю голову, но никак не получается сделать так, чтоб вертикальное меню с лого были на уровне с хедером
[image: вот что-то вроде такого. Чем-то похож на сайт ленты ру]

```css
@font-face {
 font-family: OpenSans-Bold;
 src:url(fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf);
}

* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

ul {
 list-style: none;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

body {
 background-color:#4c4c4c;
 font-family: OpenSans-Bold,sans-serif,Arial;
  padding: 87px 115px 75px 125px;
}

.wrapper {
 width: 960px;
 margin:0 auto;
}

header {
 background-color: #00aeef;
 height: 163px;
}

.header {
 float:left;
 margin:50px 40px 0px 30px;
}


.logo_head img {       /*logo */
 width: 175px;
 height: 55px;
 background: #1f2229;
 position:fixed;
}

#menuVertical {
 width: 321px;
 height: 538px;
 background: #1f2229;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Вертикальное меню</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class=wrapper>
 <header>
  <div class="header">
   <h1>Заголовок страницы</h1> 
   <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране.</p>
  </div>
 </header>
  <nav id="menuVertical">
   <div class="logo_head">
    <div class="logo"><a href="#"></a> </div>
   </div>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#1"><span>Первая ссылка</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#2"><span>Вторая ссылка(активная)</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#3"><span>Третья ссылка</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#4"><span>Личный кабинет</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#4"><span>Выйти</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
 <div class="menu"><div class="footer"></div></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Я вам советую начать верстать заново. Но сперва почитайте про `flexbox`.

Comment: Я как-то пропустил эту тему.. Спасибо большое, обязательно изучу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как я это сделал.

Поменял местами `header` И `#menuVertical`. Сделал `#menuVertical` плавающим(floating) и после этого уже блочные элементы и они не видят друг друга. И добавил `padding` с лева у `header`.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: OpenSans-Bold;
    src:url(fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf);
}

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

body {
    background-color:#4c4c4c;
    font-family: OpenSans-Bold,sans-serif,Arial;
    padding: 87px 115px 75px 125px;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

header {
    background-color: #00aeef;
    height: 163px;
    padding-left: 321px;
}

.header {
    float:left;
    margin:50px 40px 0px 30px;
}


.logo_head img {       /*logo */
    width: 175px;
    height: 55px;
    background: #1f2229;
    position:fixed;
}

#menuVertical {
    float: left;
    width: 321px;
    height: 538px;
    background: #1f2229;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Вертикальное меню</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class=wrapper>
    <nav id="menuVertical">
        <div class="logo_head">
            <div class="logo"><a href="#"></a> </div>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#1"><span>Первая ссылка</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#2"><span>Вторая ссылка(активная)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#3"><span>Третья ссылка</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#4"><span>Личный кабинет</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#4"><span>Выйти</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <header>
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Заголовок страницы</h1> 
            <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране.</p>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="menu"><div class="footer"></div></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ох, Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: Можешь кратко пояснить смысл от перестановки мест `header` и `#menuVertical`, пожалуйста.

Comment: @AlexanderMashchenko блочные элементы не видят плавающих, а плавающий если бы оставил после, то попал бы под хедер. смотри. Подробно о `floating` элементах тут прочитай. http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/blochnaya-verstka/plavayushchie-elementy

Comment: Понял, спасибо еще раз!